# Generate 2 tones audio signal

Tags: android

First of all sorry for my bad English. I do my best.

So, I have a short code (audio signal generator) which looks like below

```
 private AudioTrack generateTone(double freqHz, int durationMs)
{
    int count = (int)(44100.0 * 2.0 * (durationMs / 1000.0)) & ~1;
    short[] samples = new short[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i += 2){
        short sample = (short)(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (44100.0 / freqHz)) * 0x7FFF);
        samples[i + 0] = sample;
        samples[i + 1] = sample;
    }
    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            count * (Short.SIZE / 8), AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    track.write(samples, 0, count);
    return track;
}
```

i can call him by :

```
 AudioTrack tone = generateTone(500, 1000);
 tone.play();
```

But i need to paly 2 frequencies one after another for a half an hour.

400Hz for 1 sec, then 800 for 1 sec, then 400 again for 1 sec and so on...

How can i do it? I create 2 audioTracks tone1 and tone2:

```
AudioTrack tone = generateTone(500, 1000);
AudioTrack tone2 = generateTone(800,1000);
```

And what should i do next? Thanks for your time that you spend to answer me, and thanks for your answers! 
Oh, P.S => it's about android app....

Answer (score 0):

You can check the playback state with `getPlayState()` to see it's done.

```
        tone.play();
        do{
            SystemClock.sleep(10);
        }while (audioTrack.getPlayState()==AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);

        tone2.play();
```

Just make sure not to do it on the main thread

Comment: Thanks. But when i'm trying to do that in a new Thread. i get a message Non static method getPlayState() cannot be  referenced from a static context.

Comment: @MDobroch could you paste the code you wrote for this thread?